# Vlookup in pandas python and calculate the difference

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have many csv files in a folder and I am looking for a vlookup kind of thing. Like getting the value of another file in one and then calculating the difference.

Like I have many csv files followed by dates ( _183kOutput_data_2023-04-18.csv,_183kOutput_data_2023-03-29.csv,_183kOutput_data_2023-03-14.csv etc ).

The structures are -

_183kOutput_data_2023-04-18.csv

| Seller | Vaule |
| --- | --- |
| Hari | 2 |
| Om | 12 |
| Cat | 13 |
| Mat | 14 |
| John | 15 |

_183kOutput_data_2023-03-29.csv

| Seller | Vaule |
| --- | --- |
| Hari | 1 |
| Om | 11 |
| Cat | 12 |
| Mat | 10 |
| John | 9 |

My requirement is to take two csv files whose dates are closer and the value of one in the other and calculate the difference.

Like -

| Seller | Vaule_2023-04-18 | Vaule_2023-03-29 | Differnece |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hari | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Om | 12 | 11 | 2 |
| Cat | 13 | 12 | 2 |
| Mat | 14 | 10 | 4 |
| John | 15 | 9 | 6 |

And repeat it for all the files in the folder.
Like I have taken 2023-04-18.csv and 2023-03-29.csv now next we will take 2023-03-29.csv and 2023-03-14.csv and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import glob, os

#get files in list
files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
    
#extract dates to dictionary
names = {os.path.basename(f)[-14:-4]:f for f in files}
print (names)

#sorting by dates
cols = sorted(names.keys(), reverse=True)

#read files to DataFrames and join, last append difference column
for a, b in zip(cols, cols[1:]):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(names[a],index_col=['Seller'])['Value']
    df2 = pd.read_csv(names[b],index_col=['Seller'])['Value']
    df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=(a,b))

    df['Difference'] = df.iloc[:, 0].sub(df.iloc[:, 1])
    print(df)
```